# Why is WPF flickering on me?

Tags: wpf, alpha

I am getting very strange flickering on a WPF application of mine.  It only happens with alpha blended content, only on my computer, and only with WPF applications.  At least I haven't noticed it with anything else. It's really annoying! Has anyone else dealt with this weirdness?

[image]

Comment: Is your whole window transparent, or just some of the content inside your window?

Comment: The latter; just some of the content inside the Window.  It seems to happen whenever I use opacity other than 100%.  I should also say that the Silverlight version of the application does not exhibit these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling hardware acceleration to see if that resolves the issue.  If it does, try updating your video card drivers and turning back on hardware acceleration.  For more details, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx

Comment: That site is out of date.  There is no such registry entity as "Avalon.Graphics".  I did a search for "DisableHWAcceleration" and found nothing.  Care to update?

Comment: You have to create the entry, as it's not there by default.  Yes, I know, it's a rather ugly hidden feature, but so it goes.  It's really only intended for diagnostics.

Comment: I have to create "Avalon.Graphics" as well?

Comment: I suppose I have to restart as well?  Is there a service that I can restart?

Comment: I did so and it worked for a little while, but the flicker is back.  :(

Comment: I gave you the answer, but this still happens to me from time to time, just less now.